# About "le" replacing already mentioned ideas

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I learned the following sentences in my textbook:
"Tu es étudiante?"
"Oui, je le suis."

But my teacher told me it is not commonly used in France. People usually just say "Oui, je suis étudiante."

Is this true? Is it because *le* is usually only used to replace long sentences?

If I want to use *le*, is it placed before the verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your teacher is right. *Je le suis* is formal, somewhat ceremonial and unexpected in such a dialog.

Even to answer to a longer question, *je le suis* wouldn't be used, e.g.:

> Tu es une étudiante qui vient de Serbie pour apprendre la français ?
>
> Oui, c'est ça !

Comment: Does it mean we don't use "le" in our daily conversation as it's too formal?

Comment: We often use *le* in daily conversations, e.g. *je le prend* = "I take it", but for some reason, we do not use it in that particular phrase *je le suis*. (we use *je le suis* when it is the verb *suivre*  = "I follow him".)